# Socket not connected error when using chrome.sockets.udp

Tags: sockets, udp, google-chrome-app

I tried to run the following code as an unpacked chrome extension and got the following output in my console:

```
clicked
sent undefined
Error listening: net::ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED
```

I am also using a separate software to create a UDP server on port 11111 and it receives nothing.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "UDP Test",
    "description": "Testing UDP connection.",
    "version": "0.1",
    "app": {
        "background": {
            "scripts": ["background.js"]
         }
    },
    "minimum_chrome_version": "33",
    "sockets": {
        "udp": {
            "send": "*"
        }
    }
}
```

**background.js**

```
// On app launch
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    // Create window
    chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
        'bounds': {
            'width': 400,
            'height': 500
        }
    });
});
```

**window.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <button id="test">Run</button>
        <script src="network.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

**network.js**

```
test.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log("clicked");
    chrome.sockets.udp.create({}, function (socketInfo) {
        // The socket is created, now we can send some data
        var socketId = socketInfo.socketId;
        var arrayBuffer = stringToArrayBuffer("hello");
        chrome.sockets.udp.send(socketId, stringToArrayBuffer("hello"), "127.0.0.1", 11111, function(sendInfo) {
            console.log("sent " + sendInfo.bytesSent);
            if (sendInfo.resultCode < 0) {
                console.log("Error listening: " + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
            }
        });
    });
});

function stringToArrayBuffer(string) {
    var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(string.length * 2);
    var bufferView = new Uint16Array(buffer);
    for (var i = 0, stringLength = string.length; i < stringLength; i++) {
        bufferView = string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I have found several examples of chrome udp but they all used the experimental APIs and not this one.

Comment: How is the "test" variable being set? What is the str2ab function? Why didn't you call bind() first? (Documentation: "The socket must be bound to a local port before calling [the send] method")

Comment: test is a button on window.html that I click after the app launches. str2ab was actually meant to be stringToArrayBuffer (I have changed that now). Adding bind fixes the issue! Thanks!

Comment: I added the relevant part of the comment as an answer so you can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing bind(). The documentation says "The socket must be bound to a local port before calling [the send] method."